# How to open pdf's specific page in android web view?

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview

Can anyone help out on how to go to pdf's specific page.

```
WebView wb = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.load);
  wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
  wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
  Toast.makeText(getContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

wb.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+"http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf#page=3");
```

This loads me page 1 what should i do to open the 3rd page

Comment: Why is your code supposed to work in the way you want it to? What have you tried to solve your issue?

Comment: I have tried by adding #page3 but it loads page 1 only

Comment: Please see the following link: https://www.einfach-fuer-alle.de/artikel/checkliste-barrierefreie-pdf/Checkliste-Barrierefreies-PDF.pdf#page=2 In my browser - when I click it - it opens page 2. What browser are you using? How is your PDF created?

Comment: yes browser opens the page 2 but in the app its not opening page 2 instead it opens page 1

Comment: Then it seems to be an issue of the WebView not supporting opening PDFs on pages that way

Comment: Perhaps you should consider [other options for viewing PDFs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).